# Using index.php with includes & folders instead of named php files

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

Say I have a user database and don't want to use get to get the id (user.php?i=234) and want to use folders and index.php(s) instead (user/234)

I can do this by creating a new folder and index.php file in that folder when the user registers. I can put an include inside the index.php file (`include '/users.php'`) and call a function that builds the page (`buildUserPage(234);`)

Is this the best way to do this?

How can I get the user id based on the parent folder if 234 is the user id?

How can I check if the url of the page is index.php so I can redirect to "../"?

Comment: what you want to do is to use a apache modrewrite [Creating dynamic URLs in htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845609/creating-dynamic-urls-in-htaccess/5847426#5847426) see my answer here

Comment: alright if you post that as an answer i will accept. post the actual code though so others can see if they come across the question

Comment: there is no need, you can simply upvote the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the .htaccess file in the user directory, place the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ ../users.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For your question directory .htaccess file, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)?/?(\d+)?/?$ ../question.php?l=$1&i=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: how can i use this with multiple get variables?

Comment: Just alter the regex. Give me an example URL and how you would like to translate it, and I can help you with the rule.

Comment: Do you plan to have an actual question directory in the file system? Where will question.php reside? I assume that l can be values other than "HTML" right? Any special rules to what l can be (letters, number, underscores, dashes, etc)?

Comment: questions will be in the top directory. I was hoping I could place the .htaccess file in the /question/ directory and have question.php in the top dir and have it function. There won't be any special characters

Comment: alright thanks. and could you please let me know how to handle it when the $_get variable(s) aren't set? because right now it say file not found when i don't set the variables

Comment: I think we just need some more question marks. Try my latest update (notice more ?s).

Comment: how can I make the i variable a string instead of a number? when i use anything other than an integers I get a 404 error.

Comment: @maxhud Change the `\d` to a `\w` in the regex. [Explanation here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand)

Comment: perfect. thanks. 1 last thing. could you please please please give an example with 3 variables?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/?(\w+)?/?$ ../question.php?l=$1&i=$2&j=$3 [QSA,L]`