# htaccess giving error - 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have found a solution here, which I am looking for

> [Creating dynamic URLs in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845609/creating-dynamic-urls-in-htaccess)

so basically I modified the given htaccess code (following code is from solution)

```
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-])/?$ /view.php?mode=prod&title=$1
```

I changed it to fit my needs to

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-])/?$ /blog.php?id=$1
```

but when I visit the url `localhost/blog/1` it gives me 404 Error, that's the only line in my .htaccess file, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You say that's the only line in your .htaccess, don't you have this one too (just before yours) ?

```
RewriteEngine On
```

you .htaccess should contain at least :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-])/?$ /blog.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks Yazmat for the reply, I forgot to mentioned that I tried that but I get Internal Server Error..