# How to Use PHP Code in .htm or .html pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am writing some PHP  code in my .htm and .html pages but it's not executing the code.
I must strictly not have to change the page extension.

I have added this handler to the  `.htaccess` page

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php .html
```

My server PHP version is PHP 7.4

What I am missing, how to use PHP code in .htm and .htm pages?

I am doing this on `siteguard hosting` so if any server configuration I may missing?

Comment: You'll likely need to contact your hosting provider since this is server specific. It depends how PHP has been configured on your server. "I must strictly not have to change the page extension." - the URL or the underlying file? You can change the underlying filename without changing the URL, with a bit of URL-rewriting (using mod_rewrite) - this would be the preferred way to implement this and is not dependent on your server config so much. (I'm assuming PHP is enabled on your server to begin with?)

Comment: @MrWhite strictly does not means there are more than a thousand .htm and .html pages so must need to execute PHP code within the .htm and .html page only

Comment: Are you using Apache after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes using apache 2.0

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, be warned that Apache 2.0 is horribly outdated - the latest version of that branch is nearly nine years old!

Comment: i am using web hosting and when i checked phpinfo its showing apache 2.0

Comment: This depends on if you (the host) are running php as mod-php, fast cgi or fpm. And if the latter two, there are even more questions you need to ask (connect via proxy, what's the port...?). Check with your web host support as anyone here will only give you one of several answers unless you can provide the setup info.

Comment: this depends on what web server you are using and how your php is installed. are you using apache+php-fpm? or maybe apache+mod_php ? or maybe nginx+php-fpm? or maybe iis+php-cgi? add all that info to your main post. in the meantime, i voted to close this question as "needs details" - because it does.

Comment: Why are you unable to change the file extension? A hacky workaround if you just need to keep the URLs showing .htm/.html in the address bar would be to just create php files on the server and use rewrite rules to map the .htm/.html files back to php files with the same name. If there is an actual reason to require .htm/.html files though, that obviously won't wok

Answer (score 1):

**Here Moshe Gross's method works!**

**this is only for test purpose:**

i am tryin in xampp:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Custa">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style>p{color:red;font-size:20px;}</style>
    <p>yep yep</p>

    <?php

    echo 'wasn`t so difficult! '.time(); 
    
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**when i access http://localhost/testhtmlphp/    i got this result:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Custa">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style>p{color:red;font-size:20px;}</style>
    <p>yep yep</p>

    wasn`t so difficult! 1656790012</body>
</html>
```

re: if i press F5 (refresh page) the timer change!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the .htaccess file doesn't work on my machine. Try putting it in the virtual host configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[file name].conf)

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Tested on Debian 11 64-bit PHP 7.4, Apache 2.4.53

I don't know if your hosting will allow that modifications. It probably will work in the .htaccess file.

Hopefully it helps!

*Credit to Moshe Gross and Constantin*

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: added the line but not worked

Comment: he may also need php.ini `security.limit_extensions = .php .phar .htm .html`

Answer (score -1):

PHP able to work with CLI or .php script files otherwise doesn't work. Because before from run PHP need compile.

You can use .htaccess abilities instead write code in HTML files. Just like the following code sample.

```
RewriteRule ^view\.php?mode=prod&id=([0-9]+) /products/$1.html
```

[Creating dynamic URLs in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845609/creating-dynamic-urls-in-htaccess)

Comment: "You can use .htaccess abilities instead write code in HTML files" - Errrm, no you can't (without doing what the OP is asking)? And you have the `RewriteRule` directive "reversed" (and is incorrect as written). The code would need to be in `.php` files, but can be accessed via a `.html` URL. The type of `RewriteRule` directive you've posted would be used if you had generated a "static" HTML site from a "dynamic" PHP site - it wouldn't execute any PHP code (but, as stated, it's invalid as written and wouldn't actually do anything anyway).